# How to obtain array with numbers in between nan's?

Tags: python

I'm using following code, but it always returns array with `np.nan`. How can I fix it?

```
def func_gamma_HQ(r, rho_0, x ):

    y = func_rho_HQ(r, rho_0, x)

    gamma_HQ = []

    for i in range(len(r)):
        if i == 0 or i == len(r)-1:

            gamma_HQ.append(np.nan)

        continue

        dlogr   = np.log10(r[i+1]) - np.log10(r[i-1])

        dlogrho = np.log10(y[i+1]) - np.log10(y[i-1])

        gamma_HQ.append(dlogrho/dlogr)

    return np.array(gamma_HQ)

print func_gamma_HQ(r,  1./(2.*PI), 1. )
```

Program output:

> [nan  nan]

Comment: To clarify: r is an array of floats, rho_0 and x are constants, and the function y is already working. The error is with the last part after continue; why is this not returning anything? Indentation error? Help much appreciated..

Comment: Add the language-tag in your question like Python,Matlab, OR what?

Comment: Adrian is right, the code bellow continue is never reached, indent the continue statement in order to make it part of your if block. Then your list will grow. I have retagged your question

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is an indentation problem. Try to indent `continue` to the same level as `gamma_HQ.append(np.nan)` inside `if`. Because it seems that except for `i==0` and `i==last`, it will just jump to the next `i` without doing anything.